# Why storage:delete not working on laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, delete-file

on Controller

```
use Storage;

$postroute_ori=/images/120_5.JPG;
// Delete a single file
File::delete($postroute_ori);    <---"/images/120_5.JPG"   not work

$delfile='/public'.$postroute_ori;
dump($delfile);                  
Storage::delete($delfile);       <---"/public/images/120_5.JPG"  not work

$image_path = public_path().$postroute_ori; 
dump($image_path);
unlink($image_path);     <--"D:\AppServ\www\codo\public/images/120_5.JPG" work well

$image_path = public_path().$postroute_ori; 
dump($image_path);
Storage::delete($image_path);  <--"D:\AppServ\www\codo\public/images/120_5.JPG" not work


other method like 
use file;
file::delete($filename)     <----not work
```

Only the php method unlink work well~
How can I use the laravel storege method correctly?

Comment: `File::delete( public_path($postroute_ori) );`   before deleting make sure file that You try to delete exists (:

Comment: `Storage::delete()` is meant to be used with files that are under the storage directory, `storage_path()`. It will probably get lost anywhere else. Also, I find it quite unlikely that you are storing images in the root of your disk, you have to remember those aren't URLs, you are literally in your file system and `/` is not the root of your website, it's the root of the disk.